# How to rigourously prove that any discrete functions could be interpolated?

Tags: real-analysis

Define a discrete function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R, \ n\mapsto g(n)$

How to prove that the values of $g(n)$ could be interpolated by a smooth function:

$$\exists f\in\mathcal C^\infty:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$

s.t. $f(n)=g(n)$.

This seems obvious but I cannot find a elementary way to do this. I had tried two things:

1) Suppose $f(x)\in\mathcal C^\omega$, expend $f(x)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb N} a_mx^m$, substitute in $(n,g(n))$ and solve for $a_m$. There are two downsides. First I am not sure if the Taylor series converge in the whole domain. Second is I am not sure if it correct to solve an infinite dimensional vector $a$ like this.

2) Zero dimensional manifold can always be immersed in a first dimensional smooth manifold.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: The Lagrange polynomial will interpolate between arbitrarily many points.

Comment: You can represent each $g(n)$ by a bump function with support on $(n - \frac{1}{3}, n + \frac{1}{3})$ if you just want $C^\infty.$ If you want analytic, it is an exercise in Ahlfors that we may assign a countable set of values to a holomorphic function, as long as the set has no finite accumulation point

Comment: Ahlfors, page 196, exercise 1: suppose that $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and that the $A_n$ are arbitrary complex numbers. Show that there exists an entire function $f(z)$ which satisfies $f(a_n) = A_n.$ There is a hint, and this is in the chapter 5 called Series and Product Developments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see. The original question was just about $C^\infty,$ I was thrown off by the mention of $C^\omega;$ this answer gives  $C^\omega.$

Solve the exercise in Ahlfors for $f(z).$ As your $n$ and $g(n)$ are real, this means that the real part of $f(z)$ is a harmonic function on the whole $x,y$ plane that solves your problem; it is real analytic. Therefore its restriction to the real line is also real analytic.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between $C^\infty$ and $C^\omega$?

Comment: Never mind, I see now that it refers to [real analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759153/c-omega-notation-for-real-analytic-functions).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\exp\left(\frac{4x^2}{4x^2-1}\right)&\text{if }|x|<\frac{1}{2} \\ 
0 &\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
is a $C^{\infty}$ function supported on $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ such that $f(0)=1$.
It follows that for any real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ the function
$$ \varphi(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n\,f(x-n) $$
is a $C^\infty$ function fulfilling $f(n)=a_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Is it possible to do the similar thing to a $C^\omega$ case?

Comment: @HighGPA: yes, by the Mittag-Leffler theorem. An extra weight is also involved: see Will Jagy's answer.